# Speeding up computation of product filters when performing search

Tags: database, performance

I'am trying to find an efficient approach or algorithm to help me address the problem described below.

Let's say we have a database containing a very large collection of products. Each product has a large set of attributes, although these attributes could be shared among product. In additon, product are organized into multiple hierarchical categories. 
An example: Home -> Kitchen -> dishwashers -> GE Electric Dishwasher Model blablabla.

I would like to present to a user browsing our products a list of possible filters he could use. To illustrate it think about Amazon product filters on the side of the page: If products have a "price" attribute, then they show a slider with the lower price and the highest price as extremities. If the attribute is "brand", they have a list of all the brand for all children of a selected category. Categories and attributes are two separate concepts in our design.

My problem is all computing these filters takes time because we have a very large collection of products with dozens of attributes. Is there a particular way to perform this filtering? I was thinking about computing all filters at each level before hand but since a user may apply the filter at a higher category and keep navigating down into more specific categories, the latter categories would need to be recomputed/updated anyway.

**What we have tried**: for each product in a selected category we compute the intersection of attributes and create filters based on it. results are not cached since filters propagate from parents to children categories when applied.

PS: the database I am using is SQL server 2012. Let me know if more information is needed to better answer/understand my question. Also if you think of more appropriate tags for this question, please feel free to update it.

Comment: More info needed on the schema...

Comment: Sure, which schema info would you like to have? I was thinking more in terms of "How would one design a system to meet the requirements of this problem in the first place?"

Comment: The tables involved in the queries (at least the useful fields and indexes) along with the actual queries...